# Can I run an external display off of the Galaxy SIIX USB port?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-display

I would like to attach an external display, can that port do that? May use Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S2 supports MHL through USB, so technically, yes. You won't be able to get a full display, just through supported apps.